# Cancellation with WaitHandle

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am reading a lot on TPL and found out the ways in which we can use the cancellation mechanism. But i got stuck with WaitHandle.

If i want to cancel the task, i can define the CancellationTokenSource and pass it along with the Task and i can use ThrowIfCancellationRequested method to cancel the task.

My question is when i need to use WaitHandle for cancellation purpose, and why simple cancellation can't work in that situation?

**EDIT** MSDN link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364 .. see listening by using WaitHandle..

Just learning TPL..

Please help..

Comment: Can you elaborate on your point "When to use WaitHandle". And what do you mean by "simple cancellation"?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assume you have a signal of type [ManualResetEventSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim) and want to wait for the signal to be set, the operation to be cancelled or the operation to time out. Then you can use the [Wait method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384811) as follows:

```
if (signal.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), cancellationToken))
{
    // signal set
}
else
{
    // cancelled or timeout
}
```

But if you have a signal of type [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent), there is no such Wait method. In this case, you can use the [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx)'s  [WaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.waithandle.aspx) and the [WaitHandle.WaitAny method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190233.aspx) to achieve the same effect:

```
if (WaitHandle.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[] { signal, cancellationToken.WaitHandle },
                       TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)) == 0)
{
    // signal set
}
else
{
    // cancelled or timeout
}
```